# Half strip neighbourhoods for regular surfaces

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

> Let $S$ be a regular connected and compact surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$. It is well known that such surfaces admit a global tubular neighborhood, of thickness $\epsilon>0$.
>
> In particular, by defining the function
>   $$
> \rho:(p,t)\in
> S\times(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\mapsto p+t\cdot
> n(p),$$
>   the line segments $\{\rho(p,I_\epsilon)\}_{p\in S} $, with $I_\epsilon=(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$,
>   are pairwise disjoint.

**Question:**
Is it true that for every $p$ in $S$ there exists a small neighborhood $V$ of $p$ in $S$ such that at least one of the following two sets $$\{\rho(p,\mathbb{R}^+)\}_{p\in V}\quad,\quad \{\rho(p,\mathbb{R}^-)\}_{p\in V}$$ is made by pairwise disjoint half-lines?

Answer (score 1):

Let $S$ be the graph of the function $x^2-y^2$ in the neigbourhood of $(0,0)$ positive normals in the $(x,z)$  plane ($y=0$) are not disjoint, and neagtive normal in the $(z,y)$ plane are not disjoint.

Comment: I agree. Do you know if there is a well-known sufficient condition (not so strong as convexity) to assures that the result holds?

Comment: Convexity. Locally this means that the second fondamental form is positive (or negative) definite).